# How to obtain the list of successful tests' method names in unittest.TestResult?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I was checking the online documentation of [unittest.TestResult](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest). If I understand correctly, an instance of this class have two iterable attributes: `errors` and `failures` which return instances of `unittest.TestCase`. And then by using the `unittest.TestCase.id()` method, one can obtain the absolute package path to the `test_*` method (including its name) that was called and executed.

However, I didn't find any attribute in `unittest.TestResult` allowing to find the list of **successful** tests (after running a `unittest.TestSuite`).

So my question is how one should proceed in order to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, what I did was using inheritance. So I extended the `unittest.TestResult` class and I added a new attribute, a list to track the succesful tests. The list is updated in the following method : `wasSuccessful()`. Based on the documentation, there is no default implementation for this method so I overrod it in my extended class to achieve what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Hard to believe the `unittest.TestResult` does not contain a list of tests that passed isn't it! Did you mean to say that you overwrote the `addSuccess(self,test)` method? The `wasSuccessful()` method doesn't have the test as a parameter so that doesn't work for me. `addSuccess` does work for me, but I'm having trouble listing the exact names of the `subTests` of the passing tests... Those are important to me.

Comment: Can you please share the code?